# How to get access to the Veins Parameter "firstStepAt" in the Artery Framework?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I would like to access the Veins parameter "firstStepAt" in the Artery framework to skip the build up time from my SUMO simulation. But I cant find the part in the Artery framework, where it is possible to set Veins configuration parameter, or more general "How can I change the Veins .ned Parameters in Artery?" If someone can give me an hint for this problem it would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the value in the `omnetpp.ini`? `firstStepAt` defaults to zero, so you might need to manually add it to your `.ini` file.

Comment: In Artery these Parameter is not in the World.ned. I think i have to implement the functionality form Veins in the Artery framework.

Comment: There is a traci tree in the artery code, though, and this is addressed through the `traci` manager specified in the `World.ned` file. You'll just need to find where parameters of the veins file `TraCIScenarioManager` are set and then pass the parameters through there.

Comment: Are your sure that Artery uses the Veins `TraCIScenarioManager`? I understand the code in such a way, that Artery has is own implementation of the `TraCIScenarioManager` in the `core.cc`. But I could be worng.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but your question suggested that it does. I had a quick look before, and it looks as though artery uses some `.ned`-inheritance to do this, but I couldn't find the direct import quickly. Of course, if it doesn't use VEINS' TraCI components, you'll need to either port the functionality to artery or implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question is not so clear. I have not found the import of these `.ned` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Artery has this functionality, too: It is called `startTime` and located in [*Core.cc*](https://github.com/riebl/artery/blob/master/src/traci/Core.cc#L30).

```
scheduleAt(par("startTime"), m_connectEvent);
```

The `m_connectEvent` is used to connect to [TraCI](https://github.com/riebl/artery/blob/master/src/traci/Core.cc#L53):

```
m_traci->connect(m_launcher->launch());
```

The value of `startTime` is `0.0s` by default.

Comment: When I use this parameter i got the following exception "ASSERT: Condition 'time_cast(results[VAR_TIME_STEP].scalar) == simTime()' does not hold in function 'traciStep' at /home/baa4hi/artery/src/traci/BasicNodeManager.cc:52 -- in module (traci::Core) World.traci.core (id=6), at t=200.1s, event #2" so i thought it is something different.

Comment: Which value did you use?

Comment: I use this line in the  .ini `*.traci.core.startTime = 200s`

Comment: Can you post the result of this `time_cast(results[VAR_TIME_STEP].scalar)` statement?

Comment: This is the result ` (time_cast(results[VAR_TIME_STEP].scalar)=0.1`

Comment: I think the problem is that sumo is not running in the mean time.

Comment: This would suggest that this parameter is similar to Veins' `connectAt`. Unfortunately, there is no documentation..

Comment: This little bug was fixed recently. Can you please make sure to have checked out the current version? If the bug then still exits, please open an issue ticket on Artery's Github page.

Comment: Big thumbs up for Ventu, also thanks for the other helpful comments. I haven't checked the git in the last two days. Now it is working in the way I imagined. I found an other minor bug in this feature. I will open an issue in the git for this bug.